# Looping inside Json converted array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a json decoded array using method `json_decode($response, true);` after this i need to loop through the array and get Offer and tracking link separately, but not getting proper. Can any one help?

copying json file here

```
{"response":{"data":{"114723":{"Offer":{"id":"1","name":"name","description":"No Incent","preview_url":"http:\/\/www.google.com","currency":null,"is_expired":"0"},"TrackingLink":{"affiliate_id":"0","offer_id":0,"click_url":"url","impression_pixel":"img"}},"155655":{"Offer":{"id":"2","name":"name","description":"NO SMS No Email No Adult traffic No Bot Traffic 3G","preview_url":"url","currency":null,"is_expired":"0"},"TrackingLink":{"affiliate_id":"0","offer_id":0,"click_url":"url","impression_pixel":"img"}}}}}

foreach($response['response']['data'] as $item){
    // foreach($item as $offer){
    //   print_r($offer['preview_url']);

    //   }
    foreach($item['TrackingLink'] as $trackLink){
        print_r($trackLink);
    }
    foreach($item['Offer'] as $offer){
        print_r($offer);
    }

}
```

I need each item inside offer and tracking link dont know how to do this properly, new to php pardon me if anything is wrong

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and why that doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by _get Offer and tracking link separately_ do want separate array for both ?

Comment: I want each component inside offer and tracking link

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through arrays like this. You have done almost correct.

**Check working demo**: https://eval.in/873347

```
$data = '{"response":{"data":{"114723":{"Offer":{"id":"1","name":"name","description":"No Incent","preview_url":"http:\/\/www.google.com","currency":null,"is_expired":"0"},"TrackingLink":{"affiliate_id":"0","offer_id":0,"click_url":"url","impression_pixel":"img"}},"155655":{"Offer":{"id":"2","name":"name","description":"NO SMS No Email No Adult traffic No Bot Traffic 3G","preview_url":"url","currency":null,"is_expired":"0"},"TrackingLink":{"affiliate_id":"0","offer_id":0,"click_url":"url","impression_pixel":"<img src=\"http:\/\/tracking.sumatoad.com\/aff_i?offer_id=155655&aff_id=5073\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" \/>"}}}}}
';

$data = json_decode($data, true); // get array

foreach ($data['response']['data'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['Offer'] as $offerKey => $offerValue) { // get offer array elements
        echo "$offerKey : $offerValue <br/>";
    }
    foreach ($value['TrackingLink'] as $linkKey => $linkValue) { // get link array element
        echo "$linkKey : $linkValue <br/>";
    }
}
```